# javascript loop items after each other

Tags: loops, repeat

I'm trying to have 3 images next to each other and when the page loads they each fade in and out after each other and then repeat. I've tried creating a loop with an array of the class for each picture.

The problem is they all fade in and out at the same time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code below:

```
<script>

    $('.pic').css('opacity', 0.6);

    var picName = ["mic", "guitar", "drums"];

    for (var i=0; i<picName.length; i++) {
        $("."+picName[i]).fadeTo('slow', 1).delay( 1000 ).fadeTo('slow', 0.6);
        $("."+picName[i]).delay( 1000 );
    }
```

Comment: What is this for? $("."+picName[i]).delay( 1000 );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Christopher for all your help as I'm new to javascript. This is the final code that I've got to work as I want it.

```
$('.pic').css('opacity', 0.6);

    var picName = ["mic", "guitar", "drums"];

    setInterval(fadingPics, 9000);

    function fadingPics() {
        for (var i=0; i<picName.length; i++) {
            $("."+picName[i]).delay( 1000*i*3 ).fadeTo(1000, 1).delay( 1000 ).fadeTo(1000, 0.6);
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always setting a delay of 1000. You have to multiply this value by `i`.

```js
var picNames

$(function() {
  picNames = $('#images > div');
  picNames.css('opacity', 0.6);
  imageFlash(0);
});


function imageFlash(i) {
  picNames.eq(i).fadeTo('slow', 1).delay(1000).fadeTo('slow', 0.6);
  i++;
  if (i >= picNames.length) i = 0;
  setTimeout("imageFlash(" + i + ")", 1000);
}
```

```css
#images { white-space: nowrap; }
#images > div { display: inline-block; width: 120px; height: 120px; background: green; margin: 4px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great. How do I then make it loop through so it keeps repeating itself?

Comment: @MattLeach Is this the solution, you were looking for?

Comment: It's a bit better. Still not quite right but I'm moving in the right direction.

Comment: @MattLeach This is the answer to your question. What is missing?

Comment: This is working great to have the images fade after each other but I can't get it to repeat in a loop. When I add the setInterval it stops working. Here's what I have so far:setInterval(function() {})
   for (var i=0; i<picName.length; i++) {
    $("."+picName[i]).delay( 1000*i*2 ).fadeTo(1000, 1).delay( 1000 ).fadeTo(1000, 0.6);
   }
  },6000);